# How to serialize selected properties only

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I have one class Person and it has some public properties . Now I want to serialize person class **but with some selected properties only**. This can be achieve by making that property private but I don't want to change any property as private.

If its not possible using serialisation then, what is another way to create xml doc for object with selected properties only.

**Note: All properties must be public.**

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(person.GetType());
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, person);
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create("C://Output.xml"))
                {
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            Id = 1;
            Name = "Sam";
            Salary = 50000.00;
        }
    }
```

Current Output

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Salary>50000</Salary>
  </Person>
```

Expected Output

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <Salary>50000</Salary>
  </Person>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  an `XmlIgnore` attribute..

```
 public class Person
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            Id = 1;
            Name = "Sam";
            Salary = 50000.00;
        }
    }
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try to below code and just use XmlIgnore attribute on he properties which you not require :-

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }
```